# How to show the .kml files data table in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I want to display the object's(polygon, polyline or point) information like this image when click, how to do that in Android Studio?

.kml file can  be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hKmre9KIgVcnBoVlJucFBiWkU/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you got something?

I know kml files contains a table like this:

```
<![CDATA[<html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;">
<table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
<tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2">
<td>4114002</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
<tr>
<td>FID</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">
<td>PCAT1</td>
<td>4114002</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PCAT2</td>
<td>TG3441S</td>
</tr>
(...)
```

That contains the table in your picture for each MultiGeometry object in HTML. Does somebody know if Google has the sample code to display it in Android?

Comment: Thanks, I got the other way to implement it.

Comment: Do you have other way? Can you say it ? Thanks. I have to implement it now :S

Comment: I used Google Earth pro to create a point on the line or zone,and set information in that point, hope it can help u :).